# Cherry-pick changesets between different repos

Tags: mercurial, cherry-pick, backport

I have two mercurial repositories, `generic` and `specific`, which is a clone of the first repo:

```
$ hg glog -R generic 
@  changeset:   0:d516ded3bf0a
   summary:     generic project commit

$ hg glog -R specific 
@  changeset:   3:5f7b2efea94b
|  summary:     added another specific project change
o  changeset:   2:e2ad52001bcf
|  summary:     added generic project change (backport)
o  changeset:   1:a4220a2c7a80
|  summary:     added specific project change
o  changeset:   0:d516ded3bf0a
   summary:     generic project commit
```

Now I want to backport changeset 2 in `specific` to `generic`. I don't want to add changesets 1 and 3, just cs 2 (cherry-pick). It seems there are two alternatives: [transplant](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/TransplantExtension) and [graft](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/graft). transplant would be ok because it allows to move patches from another repository (in my case from `specific` to `generic`) but it's limited in merge capabilities. On the other hand, graft would provide smarter merge but doesn't support grafting from another repo (only between branches of the same).

The goal is to add only changeset 2 in `specific` to `generic`. This is how I proceeded, without success.

```
$ cd specific
$ hg up 0 # the common ancestor
$ hg branch backport-cs2
$ hg graft 2

$ hg glog
@  changeset:   4:1405acc4a121
|  branch:      backport-cs2
|  tag:         tip
|  parent:      0:d516ded3bf0a
|  summary:     added generic project change (backport)
|
| o  changeset:   3:5f7b2efea94b
| |  summary:     added another specific project change
| |
| o  changeset:   2:e2ad52001bcf
| |  summary:     added generic project change (backport)
| |
| o  changeset:   1:a4220a2c7a80
|/   summary:     added specific project change
|
o  changeset:   0:d516ded3bf0a
   summary:     generic project commit
```

So far so good. The last step is to pull the branch `backport-cs2` of `specific` into the *default branch* of `generic`.

```
$ cd ../generic
$ hg pull -b backport-cs2 ../specific
$ hg glog 
o  changeset:   1:1405acc4a121
|  branch:      backport-cs2
|  tag:         tip
|  summary:     added generic project change (backport)
|
@  changeset:   0:d516ded3bf0a
   summary:     generic project commit
```

Now in `generic` there is the changeset I want, but it's in a new branch while I'd like to have it in default. Any suggestion how to do that? Ideas for a better approach to backporting are appreciated as well.

Answer (score 1):

In general what you're doing is hard because it's not a very good idea.  If these projects really have that much in common they should have more in common than just changeset zero.  Ideally specific would, for example, merge in the default of 'generic' regularly -- that's a *very* common pattern.  It's possible to have 'specific' be extremely customized, or have 1000s of files that 'generic' doesn't have, or 100s of filed deleted, and the merge in will still be just great.  It's hard to do that bidirectionally, but if you've going 'generic' to 'default' you should work to keep that frequently mergeable.

As an example within a company it's not uncommon to have a repository called something like 'skel' that includes all the project boiler plate and you start of new projects as a clone of 'skel'.  When someone updates 'skel', say alters the terms of use file or something, you can merge skel into your project just fine, even if your project has gone from 8 files to 8000 -- merge still works.

That said, if you can't do that you should just use `transplant`.  Using `graft` makes for easier merges **only** because it can take recent common ancestors into account, and makes, especially, subsequent grafts easier.  None of that applies when you're just hanging it off of the first changeset -- I suspect your merges will be identical to those of the transplant case and transplant at least includes some metadata that makes transplanting the same changeset twice kick up a warning.

*That* said if you really want to go the route above just skip the `hg branch backport-cs2` line.  When you graft you'll just be creating a new head on the `default` branch in `specific` which is totally fine, and then when you do your pull you'll get a new head on default in 'specific' and then you can merge it in and it'll be on the branch you want -- but don't do that.  Use merges as intended or just use transplant if you can't.